# ERROR running force:source:push: No org configuration found for name

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, force, sfdx-plugin, cli

Not sure why this stopped working but all of the sudden sfdx forgot my org configuration.

I pulled down the latest changes from the master branch and went to push them into my checked out branch and this is the error I am getting.

`ERROR running force:source:push:  No org configuration found for name`

As you can see the org is available and connected. What would cause this to disconnect and how am I able to reconnect?

I have tried everything from `sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid...` to `sfdx force:source:deploy ...` to creating a new project. Has this happened to anyone before?

[image]

Error UPDATE:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@oclif/config'
    at Function._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/@salesforce/lazy-require/lib/LazyLoader.js:89:24)
    at require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Function._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/@salesforce/lazy-require/lib/LazyLoader.js:89:24)
    at require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/index.js:24:19)
    at Module._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
```

But I can see that the files are there:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya, this is most likely from the CLI upgrade, and installing the plugin again probably won't help.

It might be because your alias contains `.`'s in it which I didn't think worked in v6 either. Can you try to update your alias and see if that resolves it?

```
sfdx force:alias:set newAliasWithoutDots=<yourscratchorg>
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=newAliasWithoutDots
```

**Update:**

Do not plugins:install salesforcedx. This is a common mispractice and should not be done, since the CLI is bundled with salesforcedx already. It just takes up more space on your machine. The only time you would need to manually install salesforcedx is if you need to tie to a specific version or pre-release. i.e.

`sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release`

DO NOT try to install pre-release right now as we are not in pre-release season.

That missing `@oclif/config` is a known issue when installing salesforcedx in v7 and will be patched.

Comment: So should we not install salesforcedx and uninstall it ?

Comment: oh interesting. when I do this it looks like there are some files missing...I will post them in the question

Comment: Do not install salesforcedx. There is no need to since it is bundled with the CLI and it is already the latest version.

Comment: ah shoot. okay, so do you know of a work around until it is patched? Should I roll back to an older CLI version?

Comment: The fix for the plugin:install has been promoted. The aliases with dots will not be fixed as quickly. I recommend not having dots in your aliases for the meantime.

Comment: @Amphro do you know who to contact about the issue? Even when I create the alias without the dots I still get the @oclif/config issue

Comment: @Amphro so I am going to just use SourceTree as a work around as of now. Is there another way to do `sfdx force:org:open` or find the scratch orgs login credentials so I can manually open the org in a browser tab? This is the only work around I can think of...

Comment: @Olivia the config problem is from installing salesforcedx manually. Did you try to uninstall it as I mentioned in the post? What is the output of `sfdx plugins --core`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to uninstall and reinstall sfdx. You can see my solution here:

[Error: Cannot find module '@oclif/config'](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255886/error-cannot-find-module-oclif-config)

I am going to mark Amphro's answer correct as it is the answer to the post. This answer is just one way of resolving my entire issue.