# Error when running sfdx update to 7.1.3 then sfdx push errors

Tags: salesforcedx, error, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

When I ran sfdx update from 6.56.0 to 7.1.3 I got the error below.

[image: sfdx update error]

And when I run `sfdx force:source:push` I'm getting the below error.

[image]

Are these two related? I'm not sure where to start on the second error; there is no info regarding what is causing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted the `.sfdx/orgs/test-orgUserName@example.com/sourcePathInfo.json` file (which I believe resets sfdx's change tracking and pushes your entire code). This resolved the `sfdx push` error.

However it still seems that there is some issue with the latest sfdx update 7.1.3

Comment: If that fixes the issue, that is a reasonable approach. What other 7.1.3 issues are you seeing

Comment: @Amphro Just the one above- when I ran the `sfdx update` command- `MODULE_NOT_FOUND: Cannot find module './errors'` For now `sfdx push` is working

Answer (score 1):

People have been [encountering errors](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/255742/2984) with the latest version. You can try to fix this with:

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest
```

This should likely fix your push command as well.

When I just tried the upgrade command myself, I got a different error:

```
sfdx-cli: Updating CLI...
sfdx-cli: Updating CLI from 6.56.0-e3fd846a1f to 7.1.3-ece97e8491... finishing up
sfdx-cli: Updating CLI from 6.56.0-e3fd846a1f to 7.1.3-ece97e8491... done
sfdx-cli: Updating CLI...
Migrating plugins... done
sfdx-cli: Updating plugins... yarn add v1.15.2
sfdx-cli: Updating plugins... [1/4] Resolving packages...sfdx-cli: Updating plugins... [2/4] Fetching packages...sfdx-cli: Updating plugins... [3/4] Linking dependencies...sfdx-cli: Updating plugins... [4/4] Building fresh packages...sfdx-cli: Updating plugins... success Saved lockfile.sfdx-cli: Updating plugins... success Saved 0 new dependencies.sfdx-cli: Updating plugins... Done in 9.73s.sfdx-cli: Updating plugins... done
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './action/base'
  ...
```

They'll probably have this fixed shortly anyways, but you can manually fix your plugins pretty easily by reinstalling the plugin.

Comment: After running the `sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest` command. On `sfdx push` I'm getting `Error: Cannot find module '@oclif/config'` [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUFJc.png)

Comment: @shmuels Interesting. Maybe it's time to start asking around. I'll be back.

Comment: If you get the error @sfdcfox showed above, just try running `sfdx update` again. It's an error that the new v7 engine has fixed for future updates.

Comment: The update errors of `Error: Cannot find module './action/base'` and the like shouldn't matter. You can verify with `sfdx -v`. If it says v7, you successfully updated.